# Не работает телегам бот на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сервер, telegram-bot

Решил научиться писать телеграм бота на Python'е. Нашел статью на хабре на тему написания ботов для начинающих. Скопировал код и вставил в Pycharm. Все библиотеки подключены, но все равно выдает ошибку. Вот код:

```py
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('<ТОКЕН>') # здесь я не забываю вставлять токен моего бота


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start')


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

**А ошибка огромная:**

2019-10-27 11:05:28,211 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ConnectTimeout occurred, args=(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot980586311:AAGkPbroLZ1RuE-Bk0TIybIZmGdK5nMqBUE/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))"),)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 164, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot980586311:AAGkPbroLZ1RuE-Bk0TIybIZmGdK5nMqBUE/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot__init__.py", line 276, in **retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot__init**.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot980586311:AAGkPbroLZ1RuE-Bk0TIybIZmGdK5nMqBUE/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 164, in _new_conn
    % (self.host, self.timeout),
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot980586311:AAGkPbroLZ1RuE-Bk0TIybIZmGdK5nMqBUE/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/arkel/PycharmProjects/Телеграм-боты/**init**.py", line 11, in 
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot__init__.py", line 389, in polling
    self.**threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot__init**.py", line 412, in **threaded_polling
    polling_thread.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 78, in raise_exceptions
    six.reraise(self.exc_info[0], self.exc_info[1], self.exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 59, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot__init**.py", line 276, in **retrieve_updates
    updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot__init**.py", line 246, in get_updates
    json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
    return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 54, in _make_request
    timeout=(connect_timeout, read_timeout), proxies=proxy)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\arkel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 504, in send
    raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bot980586311:AAGkPbroLZ1RuE-Bk0TIybIZmGdK5nMqBUE/getUpdates?offset=1&timeout=20 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to api.telegram.org timed out. (connect timeout=3.5)'))

**Искал в инете ответ на этот вопрос, но так как не нашел, решил написать сюда**

*надеюсь на ответ*

Comment: Что помешало прочитать текст ошибки? Это одна и та же ошибка, случившаяся несколько раз. Нет соединения с сервером.

Comment: `Telegram` заблокирован на территории РФ. Не забывайте об этом. Вам следует использовать `proxy`.

Comment: Если Вы совсем новичок, то самым простым решением для Вас будет использование бесплатного VPN. Скачайте программу, запустите VPN, попробуйте повторить запуск кода.